# auto start, cross platform, background mobile web service with codename one or cordova

Tags: cordova, codenameone

I'm a newbie to mobile software development. I want to make a piece of software that:
1. I write once, and it runs on iOS, android, and windows mobile devices.
2. Has no user interface of its own.
3. Is like a web service, i.e. it lets other apps running on the same mobile device access its services via a common, language independent web service like interface.
4. Auto-starts at boot time, and runs in background all the time.

Given that i don't want to access mobile device features like camera, gps, etc. Just access to the file system, and network. Is this doable with codename one, or other CPTs like Cordova? If yes, can you please give me some pointers on how to go about making such a thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Codename One has builtin support for background polling of the web, notice that it isn't designed to run frequently as this is a battery drain.

See: https://www.codenameone.com/blog/background-fetch.html

You can also access all native device functionality via native interface calls.

However, Codename One and most mobile applications expect a user interface. What you are describing sounds a lot like a virus/spyware.

Comment: This is certainly not a virus! I'm making multiple apps. Each app may be built on a separate software stack. I want to extract all common code from these apps and run it as a service on mobile device, so that all apps, regardless of their software stack, can access the shared functionality in a consistent way. Its only strange that a desktop operating system provides ways to create a background service(daemon) without UI. Why should it be difficult to create one on a mobile operating system?

Comment: I didn't mean to offend, but you do understand the point on why this is discouraged. Apple doesn't allow these kind of apps. If it did we would have had apps like the Java virtual machine on the appstore and you would have been able to install Java apps. Apps live in isolation from one another and transferring data/control is really complex if at all possible. Android allows it but it's one of the most difficult pieces within that code. The problem with doing it has nothing to do with Codename One as this is a limitation of mobile programming in general.